# Valgrind reports memory leak on freed pointer after getline from stdin

Tags: c, gcc, valgrind, stdin, getline

Having this code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{   
    char *line = calloc(1024, 1);
    size_t size = 0;
    getline(&line, &size, stdin);
    free(line);
}
```

Valgrind complains:

```
==5931== HEAP SUMMARY:
==5931==     in use at exit: 1,024 bytes in 1 blocks
==5931==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 2 frees, 2,168 bytes allocated
==5931== 
==5931== 1,024 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==5931==    at 0x4837B65: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:752)
==5931==    by 0x10916B: main (test.c:5)
==5931== 
==5931== LEAK SUMMARY:
==5931==    definitely lost: 1,024 bytes in 1 blocks
```

I have seen other related posts but could not find an answer to this particular case :/

Answer (score 3):

This is a glibc bug (or long-standing glibc behavior, depending how you look at it):

- [getdelim leaks line when n is zero](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=19464)

It is difficult to fix in glibc because many applications assume that the line pointer does not have to be initialized when the length is zero, as in [klutt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6699433/klutt)'s [original reply](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/58670229/1). If glibc started to free or otherwise use the line pointer in the zero length case, this would result in crashes.

Comment: Note, however, that means glibc is, IMO, violating [the POSIX specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getdelim.html): "If `*lineptr` is a null pointer or if the object pointed to by `*lineptr` is of insufficient size, an object shall be allocated as if by `malloc()` or the object shall be reallocated as if by `realloc()`, respectively"  In this case, `*lineptr` is not a null pointer, so per the standard, `realloc()` shall be used on the value.  Of course, as you statied that would break improperly-written programs.

Comment: Yes, it is a POSIX conformance issue. That doesn't make it easier to fix, though.

Comment: The problem is that POSIX standardized them in a manner that is divergent from Glibc :D Thus it can be said that it is a (less long-standing) bug in POSIX.

Answer (score 0):

Both `getline` and `calloc` allocates memory. If you want to use `getline`, don't preallocate. Just do this:

```
int main(void)
{   
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t size = 0;
    getline(&line, &size, stdin);
    free(line);
}
```

A hint to this is how you call `getline`. If you were sending `line`, the function would not be able to change what the pointer is pointing to. But now you are sending `&line`, which indicates that the function wants to reallocate the memory.

If you want to preallocate, use `fgets` instead of `getline`.

Also, `main` should not be a `void` function.

Comment: yup! That was it. Thanks so much for the speedy and clear answer.

Answer (score 0):

The size contained in `size` is the *size of the current allocation pointed to by `line`*. Thus the fix would be

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{   
    char *line = calloc(1024, 1);
    size_t size = 1024;
    getline(&line, &size, stdin);
    free(line);
}
```

and it is a-ok!

Alternatively you can do

```
char *line = NULL;
size_t size = 0;
getline(&line, &size, stdin);
free(line);
```

but it might do some extra reallocs for lines that are 1000 characters long.